# Для заданного списка составить список номеров его отрицательных элементов

Tags: массивы, python, python-3.x

Для заданного списка составить список номеров его отрицательных элементов

Предположим есть 2 банальных массива

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] b = [2, 3, 5] if

Я не знаю как написать сам цикл!

Функцию нужно del Использовать?

Comment: @muralild, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Предположим есть 2 банальных массива

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [2, 3, 5]
if 


Я не знаю как написать сам цикл!!!

Comment: @muralid google > python for

Comment: Хотя бы суть подскажите т.е. я задаю список потом нужно вставить определенную функцию и просто вывести результат?

Answer (score 2):

```
def returnNegativeElements(mass)
    if element not in mass:#А список то пустой!
        return None
    for element in mass:#пройдёмся по элементам списка
        if element<0:
            resultmass.append(element)#Каждое найденое отрицательное значение будет добавлено в конец результирующего списка
    return resultmass
```

Что-то вроде того.

Comment: Только вот ТС просит номера (видимо индексы) элементов массива, а не сами отрицательные элементы.

Comment: @avp ну идея-то ясна? :)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы вернуть список номеров, где соответствующие элементы во входном списке отрицательны, можно использовать встроенную функцию `enumerate()` и списковое включение (list comprehension):

```
def negative_indices(seq):
    return [i for i, e in enumerate(seq) if e < 0]
```